# Vector (XML) drawable on splash screen on old Android versions

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-drawable

I'm struggling with creating a splash screen using (XML-based) vector drawables on old Android versions (API 16) in Xamarin.Android. I've read a lot of similar questions, but I can't get it to work no matter what I try.

I currently have the following, which works fine on recent Android versions (e.g. API 25):

**drawable/itlogotext.xml:**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" [...]>
  [...]
</vector>
```

**drawable/splash_screen.xml:**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="#3498DB" />
  </item>
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/itlogotext"
      android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

**values/styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

  [...]

  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1B6698</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

**SplashActivity.cs:**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Support.V7.App;

using JetBrains.Annotations;

[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public sealed class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        this.StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }
}
```

I have the latest support libraries (26.1.0.1, including Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 and Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, the latter depends on Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable).

Unfortunately, when I try to run the app on old Android versions (e.g. API 16), I simply get an exception saying `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_screen.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020125`, with this line at the bottom of the trace: `Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector`. Removing the `<item>` with the drawable from `splash_screen.xml` fixes the crash, but of course there's no logo in the splash screen anymore.

I have also tried adding `AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true` in constructor, static constructor, and `OnCreate`, but no matter where I put it, the result is the splash screen not being shown at all (i.e. the Android app drawer is visible until the app's main screen is shown).

How can I get XML vector drawables on splash screens to work on earlier Android versions?

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to :

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41489

As @Jon Dick said,  it should failed in < API Level 19.  In API Level 21, vector support was added to Android, so it works on API Level 21+ with no changes, since the support library would just switch to the native implementation at that point.

Here is an solution : Custom an `Android` `Application`, add the `AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true` like this :

```
[Application]
public class MainApplication : Application
{
    public static Context AppContext;

    public MainApplication()
    {

    }
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
    {
    }
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

### Update :

You could use a picture as a background when Android device version is < 21.

#### Step 1 :

Create a `values-21` folder in `Resource` folder, create a `styles.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
   <!--
        Base application theme for API 21+. This theme completely replaces
        MyTheme.Splash from BOTH res/values/styles.xml on API 21+ devices.
    -->


  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1B6698</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

A `Resource/values-v21/` directory contains resources that will be used when the device that is running your app is on API Level 21 or higher. If the device is running on an older version of Android, the `Resource/values-v21/` directory will be ignored.

#### Step 2 :

In your `Reources\values\styles.xml`, modify the `MyTheme.Splash`'s `windowNoTitle` with a different background.

**Reources\values\styles.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_low_version</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1B6698</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

**splash_screen_low_version.xml :**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item>
    <color android:color="#3498DB" />
  </item>
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/yourlogo"
      android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>
```

Please note that, **yourlogo** is a `.png` file.

Comment: As I said in the question, I have already tried `CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled` and it does not work.

Comment: @cmeeren, would you mind use a picture instead of `Vector` as a background when Android device version is < 21?

Comment: That's what I am currently doing, and what I ideally would like to change. :-)

Comment: No, I still have no solution for vector graphics on splash screens on API < 21.